# How to make a submenu in Java

Tags: java, menu, submenu

I am trying create a program that reads a file and allows the user to perform a couple of actions with that file. The nature of the program consist of the user (teacher) being asked if they would like to create a new class or load one that is in their "system"(I included a text file with the name of students in my program folder which the program will be pulling it from).There is much more to the program but I am stuck here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class GroupUs {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello, would you like to access the class that you have on file or would you like to create a new class?");

    int choice = menu();

    while (choice != 0) {
        if (choice == 1) {

            if(choice == 1) {

                System.out.println("test1");

            } else {
                System.out.println("test2");
            }


            System.out.println("test");

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
        choice = menu();
        }

    }

    public static int menu() {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( "Press 0 to quit.\n"
                + "Press 1 to access the class that you have on file.\n"
                + "Press 2 to create a new class.\n"
                );
        return scan.nextInt();
    }
```

}

Right here is where I would like for the submenu to come up

```
if(choice == 1) {

                System.out.println("test1");

            } else {
                System.out.println("test2");
            }
```

So if the user starts off by pressing 1 I want the submenu to come up with other options. If you can also explain to me how the user would break out of that and return to the original menu that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a method called `menu()` which implements the main menu.  Why not make a method called `submenu()` which implements the submenu?  Please attempt that and show us where you have problems.

Comment: Thanks @markspace ! I'm pretty new as you can tell, I'll give that a try :)